# Howto access HttpSession from a custom DataSource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, datasource

Is there a way to access HttpSession from WebApplicationContext in a custom DataSource? I implemented a custom authentication processing filter that stores some infromation in the HttpSession. This information is then used by a DataSource to obtain a database connection.

Another option is to use the SecurityContextHolder to obtain an authentication token which is customized to include additional attributes. I am not sure this is the right approach.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class CustomDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource implements ApplicationContextAware {

protected Connection getConnectionFromDriverManager(String url,
        Properties props) throws SQLException {

    // want to use the web context to get the http session

    // Authentication has a getAttribute(String name) method
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    CustomAuthenticationToken authentication = (CustomAuthenticationToken) securityContext.getAuthentication();
    Object attribute = authentication.getAttribute("db");


    // create a connection object here
    Object conn = getConnectionFromAttribute(attribute);
    return (Connection)conn;
}

private WebApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    this.context = (WebApplicationContext)applicationContext;        
}
}
```

**Update**:

I defined a new class called AuthInfo, which has username and password only. Then reated a ThreadLocal as a static final variable of a utility interface:

```
public interface WebUtils{
    public static final ThreadLocal<AuthInfo> authInfo = new ThreadLocal<AuthInfo>();
}
```

The value of the ThreadLocal is then set in the attemptAuthentication method of the filter

```
AuthInfo info = new AuthInfo();
info.setName(username);
info.setPass(password);

WebAttributes.authInfo.set(info);
```

Now, in the custom DataSource

```
protected Connection getConnectionFromDriverManager(String url,
        Properties props) throws SQLException {

    AuthInfo info = WebAttributes.authInfo.get();
    Connection conn = getConnFromAuthInfo(info);
    return conn;
}
```

Isn't this is the same as using the SecurityContextHolder and the CustomAuthenticationToken?

Answer (score 1):

In a typical multilayer application, your data access layer shouldn't have any knowledge of higher layers such as the HTTP interface.

I suggest you investigate using Spring's *session* or *request* scoping. You can create a scoped proxy bean in one of these scopes, place the authentication information in that, and inject it into the datasource.

Comment: Any good resource about using scoped proxy beans? Also, is it a bad practice to access the SecurityContext in the DataSource?

Answer (score 1):

Don't place that logic in the datasource. The http session and the database should not be related.

You can make the check in a `HandlerInterceptor` or with aspectj, around your controllers or service layer

Comment: How can I use the HandlerInterceptor to pass the authentication information to the DataSource? The authentication filter stores this information in the newly created token as well as the http session.

Comment: you should not use it in the datasource, that's the thing. You can, though, by setting it in a `ThreadLocal` variable and reading it in the datasource. But consider putting the authentication earlier in the code (interceptor), rather than when obtaining a db connection

Comment: @Bozho Spring's session and request scoped proxy beans use `ThreadLocal` under the covers, but using them instead of `ThreadLocal` makes unit-testing a bit easier.

Comment: @artbristol agreed. But it's a bad idea in general :)

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a ThreadLocal in the  attemptAuthentication method of the filter? How would the HandlerInterceptor get a hold of authentication information?

Comment: A handler interceptor might not be helpful in this case since it has access to web-level objects such as the servlet request and the ModelAndView. Any suggestions?